# Incomplete @implementation Startscreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm receiving an warning on the implentation Topscore line in the code under here:

```
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

@interface Topscore ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imageString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *urlString;
- (void)clearLabels;
@end

@implementation Topscore // Warning on this line

@synthesize count, date, urlString = _urlString, imageString = _imageString, delegate, Topscore, currentLeaderBoard, earnedAchievementCache;
```

> Incomplete implementation

My startscreen.h header file looks like the code under here:

```
@interface Startscreen : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

}
- (IBAction)tweetTapped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) startgame;

- (IBAction) showLeader;

- (IBAction) subScore;
- (IBAction) showLeader;
- (IBAction) addScore; 
- (IBAction) settings; 

-(IBAction)playSound:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)pause:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)stopmusic;



@end
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: What methods have you implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means that you have not implemented, or defined, all of the methods that you wrote in your header file.  If you define each IBAction in your implementation file, this error will go away.  For example:

```
- (IBAction)tweetTapped:(id)sender {
//Do whatever you want it do do here
}
```

Overall, the error warning just means that you need to define everything.  Because it is just a warning, your app will still build and run anyway.